# Zerotier - PORT_ERROR on MacOS

Tags: macos, vpn, zerotier

I am connected to the network, but I can't get an IP address because of the `PORT_ERROR`:

```
$ zerotier-cli join f00ba7abcdf00ba7
200 join OK

$ sudo zerotier-cli status
200 info abcd123123 1.2.12 ONLINE

$ zerotier-cli listnetworks
200 listnetworks <nwid> <name> <mac> <status> <type> <dev> <ZT assigned ips>
200 listnetworks f00ba7abcdf00ba7  1e:12:34:56:30:86 PORT_ERROR PRIVATE  -
```

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zerotier installs a custom kernel extension to the system. Starting from MacOS 10.13 (High Sierra), **you have only 30 minutes** to approve this kext.

So, the solution is:

1. Uninstall zerotier:

   `sudo "/Library/Application Support/ZeroTier/One/uninstall.sh"`
2. Install zerotier again:

   https://zerotier.com/download/
3. Open "System Preferences", then go to "Security and Privacy" -> "General" -> Click "Allow" at the bottom of the window.
4. Done! Now you can get an IP address. Don't forget to authorize the device in ZeroTier Central.

Comment: thks ... just added this one to my ever growing list of `osx_mind_fcks` document.